# Этимология слова "преставиться"

Tags: этимология

"Преставиться" — значит умереть. Но интересно бы узнать этимологию этого слова. По логике было бы "преДставиться" — Богу. А что значит - "преставиться"?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448105/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. Смысл другой.
"Пре" - это церковнославянский вариант приставки "пере": преставиться - переставиться ко Господу. Обратите внимание: правильная форма "к Господу" (к кому?) , не "Господу" (кому?). Ну или из одного мира в другой или как-то так - только не "перед".

А "преДставиться Богу" - это что-то не совсем корректное, привнесенное, не из христианской религии - точно. Бог не занимается каждым вновь прибывшим вплоть до Страшного суда, кода верующие и преДстанут перед Господом.  
Есть, правда, в церковном лексиконе слово "новопреставленный", но оно тоже не несет смысл "представления".

Вот, нашел:
Преставление (ко Господу) – смерть, кончина, ***переход*** от временной земной жизни в вечность.
(курсив мой, b-s).
http://azbyka.ru/dictionary/15/prestavlenie.shtml

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости, преставится - это калька с греческого *μετατίθεσθαι* "быть перемещенным". Приставка "пре-" (в греческом "μετα"), здесь равна "пере-".

В XI-XIII веках глагол "переставится" ещё употреблялся в значении умереть (преставится)

> м(с)цѧ октѧмбрѧ въ :ѳ͠і: переставилъсѧ а въ к҃ погрѣбенъ. Надп (В.) № 12, XI/XII; мѣ(с) октѧбрѧ (к͠е) переста‹ви›сѧ лѹ‹ка›. Надп (М.) № 190, XI2–XII; Тои (ж) веснѣ перестависѧ гюрги кн҃зь кыевѣ. ЛН XIII2, 30 (1157); перестависѧ кънѧзь мьстиславъ новегородѣ. ростиславиць. вънукъ мьстиславль м(с)цѧ июнѧ. въ •д͠і• Там же, 43 (1180); Томь же лѣ(т). перестависѧ рабъ б҃жии германъ. иерѣи ст҃го ˫акова. Там же, 48 об. (1188); Томь (ж) лѣ(т). перестависѧ игѹмени˫а м҃ри˫а. ст҃го въскр҃сени˫а. и поставиша на месте евдокию. Там же, 51 об. (1192).

Значения слова *μετατίθημι* по [Древнегреческо-русскому словарю Дворецкого](http://lingvowiki.info/w/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/83)

> 1) ставить между, помещать посреди, т. е. вносить, устраивать (τὁσον κέλαδον Hom.); 2) перемещать, **переставлять** *(выделено мной М.И.)*, переносить (τι εἰς τὸ πρόσθεν Plat.); 3) вносить изменения, (из)менять: μ. τὰς ἐπωνυμίας ἐπί τινος Her. переименовывать по имени чего-л.; μ. τι ἀντί τινος Dem. заменять что-л. чем-л.;   μετατίθεσθαι  τὴν γνώμην Her. изменять свое мнение; 4) med. отменять (νόμους Xen.): μ. τὰ εἰρημένα Xen. взять обратно свои слова; 5) превращать (τινὰ ἐς πτηνὴν φύσιν Anth.; med. τὸ κακὸν χέρδος Soph.); 6) med. исправлять (τἡν ἄγνοιαν Polyb.); 7) med. примыкать к другой стороне, переходить (πρὸς τὴν Ῥωμαίων αἵρησιν Polyb.; ἀπό τινος εἴς τι NT): ὁ μεταθέμενος Diog. L. изменивший свои (философские) взгляды, примкнувший к другой школе; 8) прекращать, оканчивать (τὸν βίον Diog. L.).

Comment: Да бростьте, какой ещё одиннадцатый век??? Он и сейчас активно употребляется. 

Ну счет кальки - ну может быть, хотя спорно. нехарактерны кальки в подобных словах... Суть, имхо, в том, что это, так оно или нет, не добавляет понимания.
На и значение "перемещенный" у этого слова, судя по всему не главное. 
Зато с русского "перемещенный" гугл переводит как Μετακίνηση, что даже такому неграмотному обормоту, как я, вполне понятно через слово "кинетика".

Comment: @behemothus, слова п**е**реставиться в значении умереть мне слышать не доводилось, да и при беглом осмотре интернета такого использования не обнаружил.

По поводу "нехарактерности"... В ЦСЯ кальки очень даже не редкость, взять хотя бы тоже самое "православие".

Значения слова *μετα-τίθημι*  в древнегреческом, дал в тексте ответа.

Comment: @Марк Из, древнегреческий язык нам здесь совсем не нужен... Хватит и византийско-среднегреческого, из Константинополя. Удивительно, что слово **преставление** в церковных словарях Алексеева (1773-1815) и Дьяченко (~1900) - не переводится на греческий. Срезневский (2,1695) дает обычное **μεταστασις**. В Лексиконе Поликарпова 1704 - целый ряд терминов приводится. *Преставитися от сего жития* - απαλλαττεσθαι и др.; *преставляюся* - απαλλαττομαι (освобождаюсь), μεθισταμαι и др.; *преставление* (изменение) - μεταστασις, αναχωρησις, απαλλαξις, χωρισμος...  На любой вкус! Латынь : **discedo e vita**

Comment: @grumant, можно и в византийско-среднегреческо - русском посмотреть, только он мне не попадался. Насколько знаю, особо сильно эти языки на письме не различались. Я бы и Древнегреческо-русский вряд ли бы стал искать, но он был среди побочных результатов поиска по вопросу.

Comment: Слова эти не библейские, а из более поздних церковных служб взяты. Поэтому разнобой и шатания. Но рыться в словарях - всегда полезно.