# Наставать/наставление и преставать/преставление — антонимы?

Tags: антонимы

Являются ли слова *наставать/наставление* и *преставать/преставление* антонимами?

Comment: Можете дать пример использования слова «престоящее» где-либо?

Comment: @shampar https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5

Comment: @qdinar Там только описки.

Comment: @М_Г да, действительно. извините, что захламляю комменты. мне стыдно, я хочу сказать, что я знал, что там ещё буква д нужна, но я почему-то не заметил этого. но, я посмотрел только первую страницу.

Comment: «Престоящий» форум — есть абсурд: престание = прекращение.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не являются.

Здесь важно правильно понимать, что такое антонимы. Это слова имеющие противоположные значения (например: правда — ложь, бедный — богатый), а вовсе не те слова, которые имеют много одинаковых букв (например: неуверенность — неумеренность) или никак не связаны между собой по смыслу (например: бузина — дядька).

Comment: изменил формулировку вопроса

Comment: Я думаю, что Вы хотите спросить что-то совсем другое, но не очень хочется заниматься телепатией. Возможно, Вас интересует не антонимичность этих слов в современном русском, а какие-то вопросы связанные с происхождением слов или что-то подобное. В таком случае будет лучше, если Вы сформулируете вопрос более развёрнуто, указав мотивацию вопроса и исходную для этой мотивации информацию. В текущей формулировке вопрос решается очень просто: смотрите в толковом словаре слова "наставление" и "преставление" и делаете выводы.